# How can I read a text file then only display the text that is between line breaks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read a text file but then only display the text that is between two line breaks.
So for example if I have this

```
 <== Line Break ==> (1)
 This is my text
 <== Line Break ==> (2)
 Some Text
 Some Text
 Some Text
 Some Text
 <== Line Break ==> (3)
 Result
 <== Line Break ==> (4)
 Some other text not needing to show
```

So as you can see above I want to display the text between "Line Break" 1 and 4 only
What I have at the moment is this:

```
 string file = "My Text File.txt";
        string[] str = null;
        if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(file)))
        {
            str = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath(file));
        }
        foreach (string s in str)
        {
            if (s.Contains("This is my text"))
            {
                btnText.Text = s.Replace(s, "Heading 1");
                btnText.OnClientClick = ReadAdvertisingTest();
            }

            else if (s.Contains("This is my failed text"))
            {
                lblError.Text = lblError.Text + "\n" + s.Replace(s, "Heading 2");
            }
        }

 private string ReadAdvertisingTest()
  {
    <== This is where I need to display the text I want to have
  }
```

The above code works great by finding the text then displaying in a `Button` but I am not sure how to get the second part to work.

**EDIT**
So the output should then be:

```
This is my text
 <== Line Break ==> (2) 
 Some Text
 Some Text
 Some Text
 Some Text
 <== Line Break ==> (3)
 Result
```

So basically keep Line break 2 and 3 (if possible)

Any suggestions would help

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output? `display the text between "Line Break" 1 and 4` is vague - including line breaks? excluding? the lines stuck together or still separated?

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary my apologies, I have updated my question with the desired output.  Thanks

Comment: Split the text by line break and you'll have an array of text lines. Then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sfile);
    
    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
        {
          
    string strwithoutSplitData = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
      if(strwithoutSplitData.Contains("<Header>") || strwithoutSplitData.Contains("<Footer>"))
    {
    
    if (strwithoutSplitData.Contains("<Footer>"))
    {
    sr.close();
    break;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    //do something
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it doesn't seem to work correctly? Its not displaying the text

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a bit ugly, but it will work:

```
string fPath = @"c:\Test5\mytext.txt";
string strBuf = File.ReadAllText(fPath);
TextBox1.Text = strBuf;

List<string> MyList = strBuf.Split(new[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

MyList.RemoveAt(0);
if (MyList.Count > 2)
   MyList.RemoveRange(3, MyList.Count - 3);
 
string strResult = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine,MyList);
TextBox2.Text = strResult;
```

So I read the text file, put it in a text box, and then 2nd text box shows the results:

[image]

In fact, this suggests quite much:

```
skip first line
grab all text to next line
include the next line
```

So, in place of that split() function, we could probably just concentate the result of the split and grab the 3 values in place of a "join", but above should suffice anyway.